# Gerando relatórios usando Top Connect em Advpl

Tags: advpl, clipper

Quando criamos relatórios, usando a linguagem Advpl, o mais prático é selecionar estes dados via Top Connect que é um software que faz interface entre a aplicação e o SGBD. Cria-se uma query que é processada e o Top retorna um arquivo temporário que será impresso.

A seguir um exemplo:

```
 Static Function RunReport(Cabec1,Cabec2,Titulo,nLin)
 Local cQuery       := ""
 Local _nCount      := 0.00 
 Private _nTotVlr   := 0.00 
 Private _nTotSal   := 0.00 

 cQuery := "SELECT SE1.E1_FILIAL, SE1.E1_NUMDP, SE1.E1_TIPO, SE1.E1_PREFIXO, SE1.E1_PARCELA, SE1.E1_EMISSAO, SE1.E1_VENCREA, SE1.E1_NOMCLI, SE1.E1_VALOR, SE1.E1_SALDO, SE1.D_E_L_E_T_ AS SITU, SE1.E1_NUM"+chr(13)
 cQuery += "FROM SE1010 SE1 "+chr(13)
 cQuery += "WHERE SE1.E1_TIPO='NF' AND SE1.E1_NUMDP<>'' "+chr(13)
 cQuery += "AND (SE1.E1_MSFIL='"+mv_par01+"')"+chr(13) 
 cQuery += "AND (SE1.E1_EMISSAO>='"+DTOS(mv_par02)+"'AND SE1.E1_EMISSAO<='"+DTOS(mv_par03)+"')"+chr(13)
 cQuery += "AND (SE1.E1_CLIENTE>='"+mv_par04+"'AND SE1.E1_CLIENTE<='"+mv_par05+"')"+chr(13)  
 cQuery += "AND SE1.R_E_C_N_O_= (SELECT MAX(SE1_2.R_E_C_N_O_) FROM SE1010 AS SE1_2 WHERE SE1.E1_FILIAL=SE1_2.E1_FILIAL AND SE1.E1_NUMDP=SE1_2.E1_NUMDP AND SE1.E1_NUM=SE1_2.E1_NUM AND SE1.E1_PARCELA=SE1_2.E1_PARCELA)"+chr(13)

 cQuery += "ORDER BY SE1.E1_NUMDP"+chr(13)

 cQuery := ChangeQuery(cQuery)

 DbUseArea(.T., "TOPCONN", TCGenQry(,,cQuery), "TEMPDUPL", .F., .T.)

 DbSelectArea("TEMPDUPL")
```

O problema desse código está no nome do arquivo temporário (TEMPDUPL), pois se um usuário estiver gerando o relatório e outro for gerar o mesmo relatório o sistema não permite.

Sei que existe uma função para resolver isso, mas não estou localizando.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode utilizar a função `GetNextAlias()`, ela devolverá um nome para ser utilizado como alias.

O fonte alterado ficaria assim:

```
Static Function RunReport(Cabec1,Cabec2,Titulo,nLin)
Local cQuery       := ""
Local _nCount      := 0.00 
Local cAlias       := GetNextAlias()

Private _nTotVlr   := 0.00 
Private _nTotSal   := 0.00 

cQuery := "SELECT SE1.E1_FILIAL, SE1.E1_NUMDP, SE1.E1_TIPO, SE1.E1_PREFIXO,    SE1.E1_PARCELA, SE1.E1_EMISSAO, SE1.E1_VENCREA, SE1.E1_NOMCLI, SE1.E1_VALOR,    SE1.E1_SALDO, SE1.D_E_L_E_T_ AS SITU, SE1.E1_NUM"+chr(13)
cQuery += "FROM SE1010 SE1 "+chr(13)
cQuery += "WHERE SE1.E1_TIPO='NF' AND SE1.E1_NUMDP<>'' "+chr(13)
cQuery += "AND (SE1.E1_MSFIL='"+mv_par01+"')"+chr(13) 
cQuery += "AND (SE1.E1_EMISSAO>='"+DTOS(mv_par02)+"'AND    SE1.E1_EMISSAO<='"+DTOS(mv_par03)+"')"+chr(13)
cQuery += "AND (SE1.E1_CLIENTE>='"+mv_par04+"'AND    SE1.E1_CLIENTE<='"+mv_par05+"')"+chr(13)  
cQuery += "AND SE1.R_E_C_N_O_= (SELECT MAX(SE1_2.R_E_C_N_O_) FROM SE1010 AS    SE1_2 WHERE SE1.E1_FILIAL=SE1_2.E1_FILIAL AND SE1.E1_NUMDP=SE1_2.E1_NUMDP AND   SE1.E1_NUM=SE1_2.E1_NUM AND SE1.E1_PARCELA=SE1_2.E1_PARCELA)"+chr(13)

cQuery += "ORDER BY SE1.E1_NUMDP"+chr(13)

cQuery := ChangeQuery(cQuery)

DbUseArea(.T., "TOPCONN", TCGenQry(,,cQuery), cAlias, .F., .T.)

DbSelectArea(cAlias)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode validar se a área esta aberta antes de executar a query e fechar ela.

```
Static Function RunReport(Cabec1,Cabec2,Titulo,nLin)
Local cQuery       := ""
Local _nCount      := 0.00 
Local cAlias       := GetNextAlias()

Private _nTotVlr   := 0.00 
Private _nTotSal   := 0.00 

cQuery := "SELECT SE1.E1_FILIAL, SE1.E1_NUMDP, SE1.E1_TIPO, SE1.E1_PREFIXO,    SE1.E1_PARCELA, SE1.E1_EMISSAO, SE1.E1_VENCREA, SE1.E1_NOMCLI, SE1.E1_VALOR,    SE1.E1_SALDO, SE1.D_E_L_E_T_ AS SITU, SE1.E1_NUM"+chr(13)
cQuery += "FROM SE1010 SE1 "+chr(13)
cQuery += "WHERE SE1.E1_TIPO='NF' AND SE1.E1_NUMDP<>'' "+chr(13)
cQuery += "AND (SE1.E1_MSFIL='"+mv_par01+"')"+chr(13) 
cQuery += "AND (SE1.E1_EMISSAO>='"+DTOS(mv_par02)+"'AND    SE1.E1_EMISSAO<='"+DTOS(mv_par03)+"')"+chr(13)
cQuery += "AND (SE1.E1_CLIENTE>='"+mv_par04+"'AND    SE1.E1_CLIENTE<='"+mv_par05+"')"+chr(13)  
cQuery += "AND SE1.R_E_C_N_O_= (SELECT MAX(SE1_2.R_E_C_N_O_) FROM SE1010 AS    SE1_2 WHERE SE1.E1_FILIAL=SE1_2.E1_FILIAL AND SE1.E1_NUMDP=SE1_2.E1_NUMDP AND   SE1.E1_NUM=SE1_2.E1_NUM AND SE1.E1_PARCELA=SE1_2.E1_PARCELA)"+chr(13)

cQuery += "ORDER BY SE1.E1_NUMDP"+chr(13)

cQuery := ChangeQuery(cQuery)

// se area aberta
if Select(cAlias) > 0
    // fecha a area
    (cAlias)->( DbCloseArea() )
endif

DbUseArea(.T., "TOPCONN", TCGenQry(,,cQuery), cAlias, .F., .T.)

DbSelectArea(cAlias)
```